# How to convert UL into 3 col table with vertical-align: middle

Tags: css

Unfortunately the CMS I am using spits out `<ul>`s as it's navigation.

I have a big menu I would like to display in 3 columns. To that effect I have:

```
#mainnav LI UL {
  display: table;
  width: 600px;
  height: 250px;
}
#mainnav LI UL LI{
  display: table-row;
  width: 33%;
}
#mainnav LI UL LI A{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

This works somewhat, but I want to have each menu item display `vertical-align: middle;`

As you can see in the image, there are large gaps where some items extend to two lines.

Would anyone know a way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: `vertical-align: middle;` is not working?

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy no I'm afraid not. I've tried it at every level.

Comment: @MeitingDog You could consider putting the items in a div element with css `display` being `block`.

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy you're wrong, display must be `inline-block` or `table-cell` as OP have. `block` display will produce a single element each line.

Comment: @Marcos Pérez Gude No, I mean having an additional  block element inside the `table-cell` element

Comment: I understand now, but OP said that the menu is built in CMS. Maybe he can't modify HTML. However, vertical alignment should work with an inline element or a text node, I can't see why vertical align doesn't work

Comment: That's why I asked the vertical align question at the very first place

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest u to make another level of UL & LI so that you can achieve exactly what you need. Like

```
#mainnav LI > UL > LI{
  display: table-row;
  width: 33%;
}
#mainnav LI > UL > LI > UL{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#mainnav LI > UL > LI > UL > LI{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#mainnav LI > UL > LI > UL > LI > A{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```